# Keras: My model loss and accuracy randomly drop to zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a rather complex sequence to sequence encoder decoder model. I run into an issue where my loss and accuracy drop to zero and I can't reproduce this error. It has nothing to do with the training data as it happens with different sets.

It seems to be learning as the loss slowly drops. Below is what it is like just before:

```
Epoch 1/2
5000/5000 [==============================] - 235s 47ms/step - loss: 0.9825 - acc: 0.7077
Epoch 2/2
5000/5000 [==============================] - 235s 47ms/step - loss: 0.9443 - acc: 0.7177
```

And here is what is like during the next mode.fit() iteration:

```
Epoch 1/2
2882/2882 [==============================] - 136s 47ms/step - loss: 0.7033 - acc: 0.4399
Epoch 2/2
2882/2882 [==============================] - 136s 47ms/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

After this, the loss and accuracy remain the same:

```
Epoch 1/2
5000/5000 [==============================] - 278s 56ms/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
5000/5000 [==============================] - 279s 56ms/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

The reason I have to train in such a manner is because I have variable input sizes and output sizes. So I have to make batches of my training data with fixed input size before I train.

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr= 0.015, decay=0.002)
out2 = model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=sgd,
             metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I need to use curriculum learning to reach sentence level predictions, so I am doing the following:
I initially train my model to output "1 word + end" token. Training on this works fine. When i start to train on "2 words + end", this problem starts to arise.

After training on 1 word, I save the model. Then I define a new model with output size for 2 words, and use the following:

```
new_model = createModel(...,num_output_words)
new_model.set_weights(old_model.get_weights())
```

I have to do this as I can't define a model with variable output length.

I can provide more information if needed. I can't find any information online.